# presentViewController not working as I'd like

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

I have my `presentViewController` code set up like this:

```
ProductViewController *vc = [[ProductViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It indeed presents the `vc` controller, but I'm unable to tap anything on it, it's like a frozen screen.  Is it because there is still a view on top of it? Or I shouldn't be using `alloc] init`?

`ProductViewController` is an existing view controller (it's actually the root view controller), so basically I'd just like the `presentViewController` to just go back to the root view controller.

Edit:

I have a `ShippingViewController` where the user enters name/shipping details.

Then they tap  on "Checkout" button that presents the `PaymentViewController` (which has a navigation bar, all other View Controllers don't).
On the `PaymentViewController`, the user enters their credit card details and tap the "Pay" button.

If the payment is successful, I wish for `ProductViewController` (the initial/root view controller) to be presented.  Currently if I am just calling `dismissViewController`, it presents `ShippingViewController`.

Comment: You do have something to tap on...? You do have to code the dismissal of the view controller.

Comment: Using alloc/init will create a new instance of the `ProductViewController`, so the code above is taking you forward to a new instance, rather than back to the existing instance.  To go back, you should use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` instead of `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: @pbasdf Makes sense, but I don't want it to go back to that view controller.  Is there a way I can set it to dismiss and then go to a certain view controller instead of the previous one?

Comment: Can you post details of your view controller hierarchy, and which VC you want to have loaded?

Comment: You may wish to read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: @pbasdf I added an Edit with those details.

Comment: @MayYang - the question refers to a "root" view controller.  Can you confirm that these vcs are contained in a UINavigationController?  If so, then you can use popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to take care of my problem:

```
NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```